# Google groups API for non GSuite accounts?

Tags: python-2.7, google-api, google-groups, google-groups-api, google-apis-explorer

The simple question is: Is the google groups API available for regular (not GSuite) google accounts?

I ask because though I followed the basic steps decribed here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started, I always receive 500 error when I try to read the properties of any of the groups owned by me, even with google's APIs Explorer.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Well, is that really such a difficult question? Even at Google indeed no one knows the answer?? (Somewhere it was stated that the questions here that are tagged with "google-..." are monitored by them.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about Google policies, not a programming question.